# possible dead-lock with nested transactions in grails service

Tags: spring, hibernate, grails, transactions

I have a transactional grails service which is doing some (long running) processing.  While processing, I would like to update a "percentComplete" value (which will ultimately be used to display a progress bar on the front-end).  This obviously has to be written immediately (i.e. not as part of the current transaction), otherwise it is of no value.

Hence, I'm using the [Grails Transaction Handling Plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/transaction-handling) and specifically the "withNewTransaction" method to start up a new transaction, within which the percentComplete attribute is updated.

My problem is that, second time around in to the "updatePercentComplete()" method, the application hangs when attempting to exit the "withNewTransaction" method (presumably when it is trying to commit the transaction).

Notes:

- if I comment out the session flushing in the main service method, there is no problem (btw, this flushing, along with clearing, is required for performance reasons in my real application)
- using the hsql database, there is no problem (see DataSources.groovy).
- also using the grails executor plugin, but I don't think this is causing any problems in itself (see the LibraryServiceTests, which also hangs and bypasses the plugin).

**Where should I go looking to debug this problem?  Maybe there are some log levels I can set in grails/hibernate somewhere to pin-point what is happening?**

The thread doing the work seems to be getting stuck trying to read from a socket, see stack trace below.  There don't appear to be any actual deadlocks in the JVM itself.

Here is my service class, link to full project below:

```
package withtransactiontest

class LibraryService {

    static transactional = true

    def sessionFactory

    def loadBooks(library) {

        int repeat = 5
        repeat.times {
            updatePercentComplete(library, it * (100 / repeat))

            // Simulate some long running process in order to be able to see percentComplete getting written to DB.
            Thread.sleep(2000)

            // Update some property (within the default transaction)
            library.name += "x"
            library.save()

            // Comment out the following, and the current method will complete successfully.
            def session = sessionFactory?.currentSession
            session?.flush()
        }

        library.percentComplete = 100
        library.save()
    }

    void updatePercentComplete(library, val) {

        println "before new transaction"
        Library.withNewTransaction {

            println "Percent complete: " + val
            library.refresh()
            library.percentComplete = val
            library.save()

            println "after save"

            // Hang here, second time around.
        }

        println "Percent complete transaction committed"
        library.refresh()
    }
}
```

[Link to grails project with integration test case which re-creates the problem](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/31611964/WithTransactionTest.zip)

Stacktrace of "worker" thread:

Thread [pool-1-thread-1] (Suspended)
    SocketInputStream.socketRead0(FileDescriptor, byte[], int, int, int) line: not available [native method]
    SocketInputStream.read(byte[], int, int) line: 129
    ReadAheadInputStream.fill(int) line: 114
    ReadAheadInputStream.readFromUnderlyingStreamIfNecessary(byte[], int, int) line: 161
    ReadAheadInputStream.read(byte[], int, int) line: 189
    MysqlIO.readFully(InputStream, byte[], int, int) line: 2499 
    MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(Buffer, int) line: 2952
    MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(Buffer) line: 2941
    MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(int) line: 3489
    MysqlIO.sendCommand(int, String, Buffer, boolean, String, int) line: 1959
    MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(StatementImpl, String, String, Buffer, int, int, int, boolean, String, Field[]) line: 2113
    JDBC4Connection(ConnectionImpl).execSQL(StatementImpl, String, int, Buffer, int, int, boolean, String, Field[], boolean) line: 2568 
    JDBC4PreparedStatement(PreparedStatement).executeInternal(int, Buffer, boolean, boolean, Field[], boolean) line: 2113
    JDBC4PreparedStatement(PreparedStatement).executeUpdate(byte[][], InputStream[], boolean[], int[], boolean[], boolean) line: 2409
    JDBC4PreparedStatement(PreparedStatement).executeUpdate(boolean, boolean) line: 2327
    JDBC4PreparedStatement(PreparedStatement).executeUpdate() line: 2312
    DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeUpdate() line: 105
    DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeUpdate() line: 105
    GroovyAwareSingleTableEntityPersister(AbstractEntityPersister).update(Serializable, Object[], Object[], Object, boolean[], int, Object, Object, String, SessionImplementor) line: 2435
    GroovyAwareSingleTableEntityPersister(AbstractEntityPersister).updateOrInsert(Serializable, Object[], Object[], Object, boolean[], int, Object, Object, String, SessionImplementor) line: 2335
    GroovyAwareSingleTableEntityPersister(AbstractEntityPersister).update(Serializable, Object[], int[], boolean, Object[], Object, Object, Object, SessionImplementor) line: 2635
    EntityUpdateAction.execute() line: 115
    ActionQueue.execute(Executable) line: 279
    ActionQueue.executeActions(List) line: 263
    ActionQueue.executeActions() line: 168
    PatchedDefaultFlushEventListener.performExecutions(EventSource) line: 46
    PatchedDefaultFlushEventListener(DefaultFlushEventListener).onFlush(FlushEvent) line: 50
    SessionImpl.flush() line: 1027
    SessionImpl.managedFlush() line: 365
    JDBCTransaction.commit() line: 137
    GrailsHibernateTransactionManager(HibernateTransactionManager).doCommit(DefaultTransactionStatus) line: 656 
    GrailsHibernateTransactionManager(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager).processCommit(DefaultTransactionStatus) line: 754 
    GrailsHibernateTransactionManager(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager).commit(TransactionStatus) line: 723
    TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionCallback) line: 147
    NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Method, Object, Object[]) line: not available [native method]
    NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Object, Object[]) line: 39
    DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Object, Object[]) line: 25
    Method.invoke(Object, Object...) line: 597
    PojoMetaMethodSite$PojoCachedMethodSite.invoke(Object, Object[]) line: 188
    PojoMetaMethodSite$PojoCachedMethodSite(PojoMetaMethodSite).call(Object, Object[]) line: 52 
    PojoMetaMethodSite$PojoCachedMethodSite(AbstractCallSite).call(Object, Object) line: 124
    GroovyDynamicMethods$_doWith_closure1.doCall(Map, Map, Closure) line: 55
    NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Method, Object, Object[]) line: not available [native method]
    NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Object, Object[]) line: 39
    DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Object, Object[]) line: 25
    Method.invoke(Object, Object...) line: 597
    PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(Object, Object[]) line: 266
    PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce(PogoMetaMethodSite).callCurrent(GroovyObject, Object[]) line: 51
    PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce(AbstractCallSite).callCurrent(GroovyObject, Object, Object, Object) line: 157
    GroovyDynamicMethods$_doWith_closure1.call(Map, Map, Closure) line: not available
    NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Method, Object, Object[]) line: not available [native method]
    NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Object, Object[]) line: 39
    DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Object, Object[]) line: 25
    Method.invoke(Object, Object...) line: 597
    PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(Object, Object[]) line: 266
    PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce(PogoMetaMethodSite).call(Object, Object[]) line: 63 
    PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce(AbstractCallSite).call(Object, Object, Object, Object) line: 132
    GroovyDynamicMethods$_doWith_closure3.doCall(Map, Closure) line: 65 
    NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Method, Object, Object[]) line: not available [native method]
    NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Object, Object[]) line: 39
    DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Object, Object[]) line: 25
    Method.invoke(Object, Object...) line: 597
    PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSite.invoke(Object, Object[]) line: 225
    PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSite(PogoMetaMethodSite).callCurrent(GroovyObject, Object[]) line: 51
    PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSite(AbstractCallSite).callCurrent(GroovyObject, Object, Object) line: 153
    GroovyDynamicMethods$_doWith_closure3.doCall(Closure) line: not available
    NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Method, Object, Object[]) line: not available [native method]
    NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Object, Object[]) line: 39
    DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Object, Object[]) line: 25
    Method.invoke(Object, Object...) line: 597
    CachedMethod.invoke(Object, Object[]) line: 90
    CachedMethod(MetaMethod).doMethodInvoke(Object, Object[]) line: 233 
    ExpandoMetaClass(MetaClassImpl).invokeMethod(Class, Object, String, Object[], boolean, boolean) line: 1058
    ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(Class, Object, String, Object[], boolean, boolean) line: 1070 
    ExpandoMetaClass(MetaClassImpl).invokeMethod(Object, String, Object[]) line: 886
    GroovyDynamicMethods$_doWith_closure3(Closure).call(Object[]) line: 282 
    ClosureStaticMetaMethod.invoke(Object, Object[]) line: 59
    StaticMetaMethodSite$StaticMetaMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(Object, Object[]) line: 148
    StaticMetaMethodSite$StaticMetaMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce(StaticMetaMethodSite).call(Object, Object[]) line: 88 
    StaticMetaMethodSite$StaticMetaMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce(AbstractCallSite).call(Object, Object) line: 124
    LibraryService.updatePercentComplete(Object, Object) line: 34
    NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Method, Object, Object[]) line: not available [native method]
    NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Object, Object[]) line: 39
    DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Object, Object[]) line: 25
    Method.invoke(Object, Object...) line: 597
    CachedMethod.invoke(Object, Object[]) line: 90
    CachedMethod(MetaMethod).doMethodInvoke(Object, Object[]) line: 233 
    ExpandoMetaClass(MetaClassImpl).invokeMethod(Class, Object, String, Object[], boolean, boolean) line: 1058
    ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(Class, Object, String, Object[], boolean, boolean) line: 1070 
    ExpandoMetaClass(MetaClassImpl).invokeMethod(Object, String, Object[]) line: 886
    ExpandoMetaClass(MetaClassImpl).invokeMethod(Class, Object, String, Object[], boolean, boolean) line: 1003
    ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(Class, Object, String, Object[], boolean, boolean) line: 1070 
    ExpandoMetaClass(MetaClassImpl).invokeMethod(Object, String, Object[]) line: 886
    PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(GroovyObject, Object[]) line: 66
    PogoMetaClassSite(AbstractCallSite).callCurrent(GroovyObject, Object, Object) line: 153 
    LibraryService$_loadBooks_closure1.doCall(Object) line: 13
    NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Method, Object, Object[]) line: not available [native method]
    NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Object, Object[]) line: 39
    DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Object, Object[]) line: 25
    Method.invoke(Object, Object...) line: 597
    CachedMethod.invoke(Object, Object[]) line: 90
    CachedMethod(MetaMethod).doMethodInvoke(Object, Object[]) line: 233 
    ExpandoMetaClass(MetaClassImpl).invokeMethod(Class, Object, String, Object[], boolean, boolean) line: 1058
    ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(Class, Object, String, Object[], boolean, boolean) line: 1070 
    ExpandoMetaClass(MetaClassImpl).invokeMethod(Object, String, Object[]) line: 886
    LibraryService$_loadBooks_closure1(Closure).call(Object[]) line: 282
    LibraryService$_loadBooks_closure1(Closure).call(Object) line: 295
    DefaultGroovyMethods.times(Number, Closure) line: 9487
    dgm$630.invoke(Object, Object[]) line: not available
    PojoMetaMethodSite$PojoMetaMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(Object, Object[]) line: 270
    PojoMetaMethodSite$PojoMetaMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce(PojoMetaMethodSite).call(Object, Object[]) line: 52
    PojoMetaMethodSite$PojoMetaMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce(AbstractCallSite).call(Object, Object) line: 124
    LibraryService.loadBooks(Object) line: 12
    LibraryService$$FastClassByCGLIB$$f97d911e.invoke(int, Object, Object[]) line: not available
    MethodProxy.invoke(Object, Object[]) line: 149
    Cglib2AopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint() line: 688
    Cglib2AopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation(ReflectiveMethodInvocation).proceed() line: 150
    TransactionInterceptor.invoke(MethodInvocation) line: 110
    Cglib2AopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation(ReflectiveMethodInvocation).proceed() line: 172
    Cglib2AopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(Object, Method, Object[], MethodProxy) line: 621 
    LibraryService$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$c098c6ba.loadBooks(Object) line: not available 
    LibraryService$loadBooks.call(Object, Object) line: not available
    LibraryController$_closure4_closure9.doCall(Object) line: 30
    NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Method, Object, Object[]) line: not available [native method]
    NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Object, Object[]) line: 39
    DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Object, Object[]) line: 25
    Method.invoke(Object, Object...) line: 597
    PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSite.invoke(Object, Object[]) line: 225
    PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSite(PogoMetaMethodSite).callCurrent(GroovyObject, Object[]) line: 51
    PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSite(AbstractCallSite).callCurrent(GroovyObject, Object) line: 149
    LibraryController$_closure4_closure9.doCall() line: not available
    NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Method, Object, Object[]) line: not available [native method]
    NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Object, Object[]) line: 39
    DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Object, Object[]) line: 25
    Method.invoke(Object, Object...) line: 597
    CachedMethod.invoke(Object, Object[]) line: 90
    CachedMethod(MetaMethod).doMethodInvoke(Object, Object[]) line: 233 
    ExpandoMetaClass(MetaClassImpl).invokeMethod(Class, Object, String, Object[], boolean, boolean) line: 1058
    ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(Class, Object, String, Object[], boolean, boolean) line: 1070 
    ExpandoMetaClass(MetaClassImpl).invokeMethod(Object, String, Object[]) line: 886
    LibraryController$_closure4_closure9(Closure).call(Object[]) line: 282
    ConvertedClosure.invokeCustom(Object, Method, Object[]) line: 51
    ConvertedClosure(ConversionHandler).invoke(Object, Method, Object[]) line: 82
    $Proxy6.call() line: not available
    java_util_concurrent_Callable$call.call(Object) line: not available 
    PersistenceContextCallableWrapper$_call_closure1.doCall(Object) line: 36
    NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Method, Object, Object[]) line: not available [native method]
    NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Object, Object[]) line: 39
    DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Object, Object[]) line: 25
    Method.invoke(Object, Object...) line: 597
    PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSite.invoke(Object, Object[]) line: 225
    PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSite(PogoMetaMethodSite).callCurrent(GroovyObject, Object[]) line: 51
    PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSite(AbstractCallSite).callCurrent(GroovyObject, Object) line: 149
    PersistenceContextCallableWrapper$_call_closure1.doCall() line: not available
    NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Method, Object, Object[]) line: not available [native method]
    NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Object, Object[]) line: 39
    DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Object, Object[]) line: 25
    Method.invoke(Object, Object...) line: 597
    CachedMethod.invoke(Object, Object[]) line: 90
    CachedMethod(MetaMethod).doMethodInvoke(Object, Object[]) line: 233 
    ExpandoMetaClass(MetaClassImpl).invokeMethod(Class, Object, String, Object[], boolean, boolean) line: 1058
    ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(Class, Object, String, Object[], boolean, boolean) line: 1070 
    ExpandoMetaClass(MetaClassImpl).invokeMethod(Object, String, Object[]) line: 886
    PersistenceContextCallableWrapper$_call_closure1(Closure).call(Object[]) line: 282
    PersistenceContextCallableWrapper$_call_closure1(Closure).call() line: 277
    Closure$call.call(Object) line: not available
    PersistenceContextCallableWrapper(PersistenceContextWrapper).wrap(Closure) line: 35
    NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Method, Object, Object[]) line: not available [native method]
    NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Object, Object[]) line: 39
    DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Object, Object[]) line: 25
    Method.invoke(Object, Object...) line: 597
    PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(Object, Object[]) line: 266
    PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce(PogoMetaMethodSite).callCurrent(GroovyObject, Object[]) line: 51
    PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce(AbstractCallSite).callCurrent(GroovyObject, Object) line: 149
    PersistenceContextCallableWrapper.call() line: 36
    FutureTask$Sync.innerRun() line: 303
    FutureTask.run() line: 138
    ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Runnable) line: 886
    ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run() line: 908
    Thread.run() line: 680

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Workaround is to introduce a new domain class, `Progress`, which has the property `percentComplete` and `belongsTo` Library.  This is updated in the new (nested) transaction, rather than the `Library` instance itself.

Comment: With this approach, if there is a problem in the long running job related to the 'Library' domain and the parent transaction is rolled back, what happens to the Progress domain?